What's the fastest way to root Dieffenbachia stem cuttings?
I have successfully rooted dieffenbachia stem cuttings in the past. The process is very slow when compared to tip cuttings and to the resprouting of the remaining stump. I searched for better ways to do it. I then realized that some growers lay them horizontally on the surface, while others lay them upright. There was nothing I saw commenting which is a better thing to do. So is it better to lay them stems flat on the surface or plant them upright? Do they need to be covered or should I expose the upper half of the cutting in each case?
